# WordPress live search and filter

Tags: wp-query, ajax, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a grid of posts on my archive page. How can I filter through them once I start typing on the search bar, or filter by category on click, please?

Comment: Could you describe in a little more detail what you are trying to achieve? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @cjbj, index.php is my default archive page for all posts. I have a search bar [input type:search] currently sitting on top of the 3 x 3 grid of posts. Then a pills navigation which links to each category via url=cat ID. I'd like to be able to filter these posts when I start typing on the search bar; or when I click on any of the nav pills without page reload. I've tried a bunch of random code so far, nothing has worked.